# mget command in Windows command line FTP client does not download files

Tags: windows, csv, batch-file, cmd, ftp

I'm trying to achieve something simple - other solutions I've found have not worked for me.

I want to use the windows scheduler to run a cmd file, to FTP to a server, and download all of the *.csv files in the default directory, the local directory the file is being run from.

Files in the remote directory are:

20161101.csv
...
20161129.csv

I created this file, and called it d.ftp:

```
open 123.345.456.567
username
password
binary
mget *.csv
disconnect
quit
```

I then go to the windows command (CMD) and type:

```
ftp -s:d.ftp
```

All that happens is I see:

```
ftp> open 123.345.456.567
Connected to 123.345.456.567
220
User (123.345.456.567:(none)):
331 Password required for username (actual username is shown on the screen)

230 User username logged in.
ftp> binary
200 Type set to I.
ftp> mget *.csv
200 Type set to I.
mget 20161101.csv? disconnect
mget 20161102.csv? quit
ftp>
```

No files are copied to my local directory, no CSV files are transferred.

Any ideas?

Thanks for any help.

Mark

Comment: Try doing it manually first via cmd to check whats happening? I've had problems my self with the ftp command.

Comment: Hi - I can connect via FTP one command at a time, with no issue - but I want to do it overnight, so needed to group the commands together.

Comment: Try adding the `-n` switch to suppress auto-login.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the [`prompt` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ftp-prompt_1) or the [`-i` command-line switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ftp) to suppress the confirmation prompts (`mget 20161101.csv?`) before each file transfer.

```
open 123.345.456.567
username
password
binary
prompt
mget *.csv
disconnect
quit
```

Comment: Thank you - I added the -i switch, and it worked straight away.